# Qt project doesn't compile, undefined reference to

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, undefined-reference, qapplication

`Main.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

`test.pro`

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION,4) : QT +=widgets
```

`outputs :`

[image]

I can't compile my project because of "undefined reference to", it seems that my compiler doesn't find "QApplication" but i don't know how to solve it.
I unistall and reinstall my Qt but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Is this your full `test.pro`? Did you add the proper type for your application? It seems that it's looking for WinMain and not main, which means bad setup.

Comment: You need to add the according libraries, not just the includes, to your linker commandline. Also, make sure that you do a little research on the error message before asking next time, because this isn't an uncommon error!

Comment: yes, it is, I found my problem that the compiler was 64 bit compiler, i selected my 32 bit compiler and i don't match any error ....

Answer (score 0):

Check complier type 'MinGW 64-bit'.
You can change type: Projects->Build & Run 64-bit or 32-bit (target devices)

Link:[Qt Creator](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KriIi5EFCn_u-vAjt3rXH7KK4yMrTFZH/view?usp=sharing)